# Android layout with navigation drawer

Tags: android-layout, layout, android-viewpager, android

I am new to android, and developing a practice app using navigation drawer. I want to make the main view to be a pager with 3 tabs, and a navigation drawer could show up when user slide from left to right.

Here is my **Main.xml** code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    tools:context=".ExampleMain" >

<!-- 
    Main Content place holder
 -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<!-- 
    Left Drawer main style
 -->
<ListView
    style="@style/HighlightColor"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In which the `<Framelayout>` should contain my actual main view defined in another xml **Main_Content.xml**

```
<andriod.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I am not sure how I can put the `Viewpager` in **Main_Content.xml** to the `<FrameLayout>` section in **Main.xml**. Please provide some example code or some pointer. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you shouldn't use ActionBar tabs with the NavigationDrawer:

> "You shouldn't use navigation drawers with action bar tabs. If you're aiming for a UI similar to that of Google Play Music, you should implement tabs manually (and beware of how this looks on tablet—you don't want full-width tab bars on tablets). Also make sure to check out the [Structure in Android App Design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpqyiBR0lJ4) session from this year's Google I/O for a detailed run-through of the various interface patterns available for exposing app hierarchy." - [Roman Nurik, Android Developer Advocate @ Google](https://plus.google.com/u/1/116515063230772720916/posts/8dWEkFcbTFX)

Using [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) in the `Activity` that inflates `Main.xml`:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_content, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`ExampleFragment` will contain the method `onCreateView()` that will [Inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29) your XML:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, 
                                   ViewGroup container, 
                                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.Main_Content, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I couldn't find the further explanation from your Google+ link on the drawback of using navigation drawer and actionbar tabs together. Can you please explain some more drawback on this? I will take a look at the Google IO app as well=)

Comment: Sorry I saw the discussion on the G+ page just now.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Essentially, Google recommends that you include [swipe views](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) with your navigation tabs. The NavigationDrawer can be opened with a left-to-right swipe and dismissed with a right-to-left swipe (among others). Now, imagine that the user swipes left-to-right with the intent of navigating through the tabs. However, the swipe is now ambiguous since the swipe is registered to both the NavigationDrawer and the tabs.

Comment: Watch the [Structure in Android App Design @ 23:47](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=XpqyiBR0lJ4#t=1427)

Comment: Another gotcha for me was using swipe-navigation between tabs while one tab was implementing a MapView. When you were on the map tab, swiping simply navigated the map!

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. for the swipe conflicting issue, acutually I don't really need the fragments in the pager to be swipable. Can you please point some ways that I can disable the pager swiping and only register swipe with navigation drawer?

Comment: Assuming you're using the [ActionBar tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), the three steps are: 
(1) Implement the ActionBar.TabListener interface.
(2) For each tab you want to add, instantiate an ActionBar.Tab and set the ActionBar.TabListener by calling setTabListener().
(3) Then add each tab to the action bar by calling addTab().

Comment: 问题解决了吗？我也正需要一个NavigationDrawer +可以滑动的SwipeTab的实现.有代码例子么..你别看他说这不符合android设计规范,结果google paly store,music 都用这种模式..弊端就是你从左向右滑可能有误操作导致抽屉被划出来.

Answer (score 1):

You may use it in the following manner:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        tools:context=".ExampleMain" >

    <!-- 
        Main Content place holder
     -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <andriod.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/main_content_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- 
        Left Drawer main style
     -->
    <ListView
        style="@style/HighlightColor"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawer as per design is designed in such a way that it will show up if you try to swipe from 20dp margin of left (or right) part of the screen.

**EDIT 1:**
In case you want to put the views in separate xmls you can very well do that and add the views at run time.

Write another xmls as follows:
**view_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout" >

    <!-- 
        Main Content place holder
     -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!-- 
        Left Drawer main style
     -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then in the onCreate of your activity you can the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
                ViewPage pager = (ViewPager) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.view_pager, null, false);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
                container.addView(pager);
               }
```

I hope it Helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually tried this and it raised an error: `11-04 23:54:33.414: E/AndroidRuntime(936): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.ui.ExampleMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class andriod.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

Comment: Also, I have a little concern if this will be somewhat tightly coupled by putting everything into one xml. Could there be an solution to keep the view components in two files, and put the components together at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it dynamically by inflating your layout or if its a static layout, you can use the include tag.

If its a static one :

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include layout="@layout/your_layout"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

But since you are using the navigation drawe, i hope what you need is dynamic one.
So from code, what you need to do is :

```
private void onNavigationClicked(){
    View v=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main_content);
    fl.removeAllViews();
    fl.addView(v);
    fl.invalidate();
}
```